# Helm --set with > as special Charcater at the end

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, helm3

I need help with helm cli because I have a password that end with '>'. I am usisng
helm v3.9.0 with go1.17.5 on windows machine

My password is like 123456hJcx>

So to create a secret I need to inyect this values when executing the helm command

```
helm upgrade --install ..... --set dbPass=123456hJcx>
```

This give the the error: The syntaxt of the command is incorrect so I tried to remove the '>' just to check if this was the issue and yes, if I remove the '>' there are no errors.
I have tried to scape it like this

```
helm upgrade --install ..... --set dbPass=123456hJcx\>
```

also to quote it

```
helm upgrade --install ..... --set dbPass='123456hJcx>'
```

```
helm upgrade --install ..... --set 'dbPass=123456hJcx>'
```

and also quote and scape

```
helm upgrade --install ..... --set dbPass='123456hJcx\>'
```

```
helm upgrade --install --dubug --dry-run ..... --set 'dbPass=123456hJcx\>'
```

but nothing works....

in some cases it return this
[image]

and thats it but if I just removbe the '>' it works perfect I see all the manifest but the password will be incorrect
[image]

Any help for that

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's the actual error?  The black-and-red-and-blue images are pretty hard to read; can you [edit] the question to replace them with the actual text of the error?  Note that `helm install --set` has some unusual syntax and you will hit additional problems if the password contains `{` or `.`, and it may be more reliable to write this setting into a YAML or JSON file that you can pass with `helm install -f`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i forgot this is windows to scape use "

https://www.howtogeek.com/694949/how-to-escape-spaces-in-file-paths-on-the-windows-command-line/

**FIX:**

```
helm upgrade --install ..... --set dbPass="123456hJcx>"
```